# Format DateTime in Text Box in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

Is there an easy way to format the display of a `DateTime` value in a Rails view?

For example, if I'm doing something like:

```
<%= text_field :my_object, :start_date %>
```

and only want to display the Date part of the `:start_date` (i.e. I want to hide the time part), is there a way to format the `:start_date` string inside of the view such that it will work for creating new `my_object` items and updating new `my_object` items?

Just a clarification:

Doing

```
<%= text_field 
       :my_object,
       :start_date,
       :value => @my_object.start_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') %>
```

works *beautifully* when the object already exists (i.e. on item updates), however, when creating a **new** item, since start_date will initially be nil, the view will throw an error

```
while evaluating nil.strftime
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Some great suggestions here, however in those cases where you really do want your text field date formatted a specific way (say you're integrating with a javascript date picker), and you're dealing with nils, I think simply making a minor tweak to your existing method would do the trick:

```
:value => (@object.start_date.blank? ? '' : @object.start_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
```

Comment: You're missing a closing paren at the end, but otherwise this is what I did at first.  I eventually went the route of just initializing the `start_date` to the current date in the object, so that `start_date` would never be `nil` in the first place.

Comment: Even cleaner: value: ( @object.start_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') unless @object.start_date.blank?)

Comment: @OleHenrikSkogstrøm nil is not the same as an empty string (which the datepickers I've used required). Definitely use an unless like that though if it works for you.

Answer (score 7):

I can think of three ways:

1) Creating a new method on the model that would format your date however you need it to be

2) Creating a helper method that would do the same

3) Have you tried doing:

```
<%= text_field 
   :my_object,
   :start_date,
   :value => @my_object.try(:start_date).try(:strftime,'%m/%d/%Y') %>
```

Answer (score 4):

If your form is tied to an object, (something like `<% form_for(:object) do |f| %>`) you should use `<%= f.text_field :start_date, :value => f.object.start_date.to_s(:date_format) %>`

then you can register your `:date_format` in config/environment.rb

Not sure why you want to do this, but i hope it's for presentation purposes only.

Comment: It's mostly to prevent someone from thinking they need to or should input a time.  For most users "2019-09-10 17:00:18" just isn't friendly.  I'd much rather just be displaying "09/10/2009" since the time part is completely unnecessary for what I'm doing.

Comment: then you should use select_date helper instead of plain input

Comment: Agree, if it's for selecting a date, a Calendar or select_date helper are better approaches

Comment: I am using a calendar control, which works great when selecting a date -- you put the cursor in the text box, select the date from the calendar, and see your selection get written to the textbox.  However, when going back to the page, the textbox is going to display the datetime from the DB, meaning that it will again have the time in there -- which is confusing.  I'd personally rather not use select_date since the usability doesn't seem near as high as the calendar control I'm already using.  Does that make sense?

Comment: this worked for me with one adjustment: `:value => (f.object.start_date.to_s(:date_format) unless f.object.start_date.nil?)`

Answer (score 2):

In my application_helper.rb I put

```
def nice_date_form(the_date)
   return the_date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
end
```

In any edit.html.erb view file with a jQuery datepicker I then use:

```
<% if @activity.end_date? %> 
    <%= f.text_field :end_date, :value => nice_date_form(@activity.end_date) %>
<% else %>
    <%= f.text_field :end_date %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @jerhinesmith You are absolute right. Did not test that properly.
I changed the code above to test for nil. You could also do that the way Dave Rapin did it, in a nice one-liner.

Comment: what if you changed `nice_date_form` to something like `return (the_date ? the_date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') : '')`.  Then, you should be able to remove the conditional from the view.

Comment: @jerhinesmith
Sure, or going with Dave Rapin's idea, it would look like this:
    <%= f.text_field :start_date, :value => (@activity.start_date.blank? ? '' : nice_date_form(@activity.start_date)) %>
One liners are great if you can see the logic in them. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This can be handled DRYly at the model layer using the Rails-provided `<attribute>_before_type_cast` method variant. Rails already uses this method for doing just this type of formatting, so we're just overwriting the default. For example:

```
class MyModel
   def start_date_before_type_cast
      return unless self[:start_date]
      self[:start_date].strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
   end
end
```

This way, anywhere you have a text field for the MyModel#start_date field you get formatting for "free".

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to enter the date in a textfield, but in a less error prone select field, you could use the [ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html), [select_date()](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#M001702). see [Accessing date() variables send from the date helper in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388573/accessing-date-variables-send-from-the-date-helper-in-rails) here on SO on how to process the return values.

Answer (score 0):

In a helper

```
def l(value, options = {})
   return nil unless value.present?
   value = value.to_date if value.is_a? String
   super(value, options)
end
```

Then in the view

```
<%= f.text_field :end_date, class: "datepicker" :value => l(@activity.end_date) %>
```

Here `l` is a rails helper (`I18n.l`) which can be **locale specific** and can take a format. Examples:

```
l(@activity.end_date, format: :short)
l(@activity.end_date, format: "%d-%m-%Y")
```