# How do I format date and/or time input in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, formatting, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This question is asking virtually the same as this:

- [Rails date format in form field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443094/rails-date-format-in-form-field)

Except the top answer is not working for me. I'm new to both Ruby and RoR, so I'm not sure what the heck am I doing anyway. Here is what I have so far.

I've added the default date and time format in my `en.yml`:

```
en:
  date:
    formats:
      default: '%d.%m.%Y'
  time:
    formats:
      default: '%H:%M'
```

I've also added a new initializer with the following code:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = '%d.%m.%Y'
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = '%H:%M'
```

When I go to rails console and do `Time.now.to_s` or `Date.today.to_s` I get correct results. These also display correctly when fetched from the database and shown on a model index page for example.

However, when I try to create a form with some date and time fields (not datetime!), I get the good old `YYYY-MM-DD` for dates, and the whole `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.nnnnnn` for time.

What would be the best practise to format these input values correctly? I'd like to avoid changing anything in the view (like it's done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422274/format-datetime-in-text-box-in-rails)), and solve this properly - on the application level - if it's possible at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

First I've defined a custom field in the model:

```
  attr_accessible :entry_date_formatted

  def entry_date_formatted
    self.entry_date.strftime '%d.%m.%Y' unless self.entry_date.nil?
  end

  def entry_date_formatted=(value)
    return if value.nil? or value.blank?
    self.entry_date = DateTime.strptime(value, '%d.%m.%Y').to_date
  end
```

Then I've changed my form from `entry_date` to `entry_date_formatted`:

```
<%= form.text_field :entry_date_formatted, :placeholder => 'Date' %>
```

Last but not least, I've added the relevant fields to my locale file:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      time_entry:
        entry_date_formatted: Entry date
        start_time_formatted: Start time
        end_time_formatted: End time
```

This is probably not the best way, but it serves me well for now.